# Using jQuery hover with css properties

Tags: jquery, css, hover

I suspect my problem is something beyond the implementation here. This code is not working.  I compared it against similar forum posts, checked and re-checked.  Can anyone offer another set of eyes.  Thanks!

HTML:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javacript"    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js">  </script>
<script type="text/javacript" src="mouseAction.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="screen">
      <div class="button"></div>
  <!-- end .screen --></div>
```

CSS:

```
.button {
    display    : block;
    float      :right;
    background : url(images/playButton.png) no-repeat;
    height     : 151px;
    width      : 154px;
    margin     : 140px 216px 0px 0px;
}
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".button").hover(function () {
        $(this).css("background", "url(images/playButton_S2.png)");
    }, 
    function () {
        $(this).css("background", "url(images/playButton.png)");
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? What is the exact problem? What have you tried?

Answer (score 3):

without actually firing up the code, one thing that stands out is
"text/javacript"
should be
"text/javascript"

Comment: Yep. That was it is. An f'ing "s". *&^%%^&^!

Comment: THANKS. I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I put in an Alert at the beginning of the script and it didn't trigger. So I knew it had to be the sources.  Son of a GUN!

Comment: all part of the learning fun - the little facepalms are often the most sanity threatening :)

Answer (score 0):

To get jQuery working properly with background images, use background-image instead of background.

CSS:

```
.button {
display    : block;
float      :right;
background-image : url(images/playButton.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height     : 151px;
width      : 154px;
margin     : 140px 216px 0px 0px;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".button").hover(function () {
    $(this).css("background-image", "url(images/playButton_S2.png)");
}, 
function () {
    $(this).css("background-image", "url(images/playButton.png)");
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the answer you're looking for, but why not just use plain css instead of javascript for this simple task? This would do the trick :

```
.button {
    display    : block;
    float      :right;
    background : url(images/playButton.png) no-repeat;
    height     : 151px;
    width      : 154px;
    margin     : 140px 216px 0px 0px;
}

.button:hover {
   background-image: url(images/playButton_S2.png);
}
```

Comment: The issue most of us have with :hover is that it doesn't work in IE6. Yes, we all hate it, but most of the websites that I create and work on have to include IE6 support.

Comment: Yeah it is indeed a concern. That being said, that div.button could have been a regular <a> tag too (wich is probably more approriate for a button anyway) and IE6 would handle it just fine.

Answer (score 0):

1st You need to give your button div an ID & fix the 'javacript' spelling:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js">  </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="mouseAction.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="screen">
      <div class="button" id="divButton"></div>
</div>
```

Your jQuery is all wrong also..try this:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     var btn = $("#divButton");
     btn.hover(function() {
     btn.css("background-image", "url(images/Error.gif)");
     });

     btn.css("background-image", "url(images/Success.gif)");
 });
```

I didn't see any CSS for your screen div..add this to your CSS & modify as you need

```
.screen {
    background-color: silver;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    }
```